# Asp.Net MVC Model with related drop downs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am building a screen in my C# Asp.Net MVC application, which has a few related drop downs.So, for example, I select 'Category', and then a 2nd drop down should display all related sub categories for the selected category.

So, would the model contain a List, used to build the Category drop down, and then a List, initially empty. On the selection of the category, I need to do a post back, passing back the id if the selected Category, then populate the List<> Sub Categories... and then build the Sub Category drop down?

Hopefully someone can assist with the design of my model. The model would also have quite a few non-list related data for the item being edited. And I think the model would also need a 'CategorySelectedId', so that I know what was selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nicest  way is to use AJAX for this. You'll have to hook the `change` event to your first select box, and once it is changed, you'll do a AJAX request with the selected value to some `Action`. The action will return a JSON list, which will be parsed and put in the next `select box`.

**Update**

The model for the JSON returning action can be an anonymous type really, or a `IEnumerable` of `SelectListItem`. Use  `Linq`: `mycollection.select(item=> new SelectListItem() { Name = item.Name, Value = item.ID.ToString() });

If we assume the page looks like this:

```
<form>
   <select id="MainCat" name="MainCatID">
      <option value="1">First option</option>
      <option value="2">First option</option>
      <option value="3">First option</option>
   </select>

   <select id="SubCat" name="SubCatID" disabled="disabled">
      <option value=""> -- Please select a main category -- </option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Your model would look like:

```
public class MyModel {
    public int MainCatID {get;set;}
    public int SubCatID {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MainCats {get;set;}
}
```

Of course you could add validation attributes etc.

Comment: Thnaks @Gidon - What would the Model look like?

Comment: Thnaks @Gidon - I would need the model to have the vlues for the drop mdown too, right? That is, the list of items and their values, to populate the drop down?

Comment: For the first dropdown, yes you could. I've added it to the model.

Comment: Thanks. In the mark up, would you then use a foreach to build the items from the MainCats? I've been doing this, but then been told that I shouldn't be using foreach in my View...

Comment: There are two parts in your question. How should I display the maincats dropdown: in this case the easiest is to use Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.MainCatID, Model.MainCats)

Comment: The second part is , should I use foreach loops in my view. Yeah sure. It is used to make a UL list or a table. And even if you want to have more control over your <select> list (for example print out CSS classes on option elements.    
With Razor syntax your code will also be less messy when using foreach loops.